# Banner getting ignored

Tags: html, css

I want to put a navigation under my banner, but when I try to do that it just goes behind my banner (it pretends it isn't there. This is solved by removing position: absolute; but when I do that my banner wont be on top left anymore.

```
<img class="banner" src="images/banner.png">
<nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Prijzen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Examen</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Leerlingen</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

css:

```
.banner
{
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute; 
}


.navigation
{

}
```

Comment: So add `margin-top` to your navigation.  Absolutely positioned elements *do not affect positioning of other elements*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to use a container for your banner and for your menu like this:

**html**

```
<div class="navCont">
    <div class="banner">BANNER</div>
    <nav class="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Prijzen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Examen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Leerlingen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.banner
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    position: relative;
    background: yellow;
    float: left;
}

.navigation{
    float:left;
}
```

Also i suggest to use `position:relative` and `float` instead of `position:absolute`.

Take a look to this example:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L4Tmq/9/)

Comment: Hi thanks for reply, but now there is white space left/right and top from the banner, thats the reason I used position absolute. Do you know how to fix this??

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position: relative` to `.navigation`

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/xf4Te/)**

```
.navigation {
    position: relative;
}
```